# How to rename appendices according to the chapter number

Tags: chapters, appendices, appendix, titling

I'm writing a book that includes some chapters. In some chapters, it's needed to prepare one or more appendices. Preparing a code for this style is simple as follows

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}  

\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{two}  
\lipsum[4-10]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{app2.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{app2.2}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{appendices}


\chapter{three}  

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{app3.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{appendices}



\chapter{four}  
\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{five}  
\lipsum[4-10]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{app5.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{app5.2}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

As is clear, the appendices are `Appendix A`, `Appendix B`, and so on, regardless of the chapter number. But I want to rename them according to the chapter number such as `Appendix 2.A`, `Appendix 2.B`, `Appendix 3.A`,  and so on. How shall I change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make appendices behave that way, you should be using subappendices and sections.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}  

\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{two}\label{test}
\lipsum[4-10]

\begin{subappendices}

\section{app2.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\section{app2.2}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{subappendices}

\chapter{three}  

\begin{subappendices}

\section{app3.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{subappendices}

\chapter{four}  
\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{five}  
\lipsum[4-10]

\begin{subappendices}

\section{app5.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\section{app5.2}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses etoolbox to modify the appendices package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}}{\setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}}{}{1}
\pretocmd{\appendices}{\edef\currentchapter{\thechapter}\setcounter{@ppsaveapp}{0}}{}{2}
\apptocmd{\appendices}{\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\currentchapter.\Alph{chapter}}}{}{3}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}  

\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{two}\label{test}
\lipsum[4-10]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{app2.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{app2.2}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{appendices}

\chapter{three}  

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{app3.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{appendices}

\chapter{four}  
\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{five}  
\lipsum[4-10]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{app5.1}
\lipsum[4-10]

\chapter{app5.2}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @John Kormylo. Many thanks for your answer, but the answer adds the apprentices as a section while I want them to be as an individual chapter but in the appendix shape having name according to the parent chapter.

Comment: Okay, but there currently isn't enough room in the TOC for chapter numbers like 2.A.

Comment: It's OK. It'll be modified later.

Comment: Dear @John Kormylo, thank you so much. It works nicely.